# finite flat commutative group schemes arising from Abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-schemes, abelian-schemes

How are the finite flat group schemes $\mathcal{A}[\ell^n]$ arising from an Abelian scheme $\mathcal{A}/S$ singled out among other finite flat commutative group schemes of exponent $\ell^n$?

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of a finite flat group scheme of exponent $\ell^n$ that doesn't come from the $\ell^n$-torsion in an abelian variety?

Comment: @Scott: a group scheme killed by $\ell$ won't be the $\ell$-torsion in an abelian variety if it has order $\ell^n$ with $n$ odd. And there are other obstructions other than this: e.g. a group scheme of order $\ell^2$ and killed by $\ell$ won't be the $\ell$-torsion in an elliptic curve if it's not self-dual (by the Weil pairing); but even this isn't enough; e.g. $\alpha_\ell\times\alpha_\ell$ isn't the $\ell$-torsion in a characteristic $\ell$ elliptic curve either, because of a formal group argument. My gut feeling is that there is unlikely to be a simple neat criterion.

Comment: If there were a simple criterion which told you precisely when a 2-dimensional mod $\ell$ Galois representation of the absolute Galois group of the rationals were the $\ell$-torsion in an elliptic curve, then we would have known lots of new cases of Serre's conjecture the moment Taniyama-Shimura-Weil was proved---and this didn't happen, so this is more evidence that the question may well not really admit a satisfactory answer.

Comment: By the way, there is also an article by Christian Liedtke, entitle "The p-torsion subgroup scheme of elliptic curves"
http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.1307
in which he studies what kind of twisted forms of $\mathbb Z/p \oplus \mu_p$ can be realized as p-torsion of elliptic curves over fields of characteristic p.

Answer (score 9):

Is the abelian scheme you consider a fixed one?

If the base is of characteristic $p$, and $l = p$ then the Lie algebra of $A[l]$ is isomorphic to $Lie(A)$, so you get a dimension condition.

For example, $\alpha_p \oplus \alpha_p$ cannot be embedded in an elliptic curve.

There are also more general condition your group scheme $G$ should satisfy.
Assume that $S$ is the spectrum of an Artinian algebra and that
$G$ is $p$-torsion with a trivial bi-nilpotent part.
We have an exact sequence:
$$ 0 \to G^{mult} \to G \to G^{et} \to 0$$

then the orders of $G^{mult}$ and $G^{et}$ must be equal if $G$ is the $p$-torsion of an abelian scheme.

On the other hand, in section (15.4) of the book "Commutative group schemes" of F. Oort, there is the following result:

Every finite flat commutative group scheme is a subgroup scheme of some abelian variety $A$.

Comment: @Holger: could you say where is the statement you quote from Oort's book ? 

Comment: Excuse me for not giving the exact reference. Today I am nowhere near the library so I cannot fix it right now, but it's on my list for tomorrow.

Comment: The statement is at the beginning of section (15.4): Finite subgroups of abelian varieties

Comment: Here is a related result, due to Raynaud : every finite locally free commutative group scheme $G$ over a scheme $S$ can be embedded into a projective abelian scheme, Zariski locally over $S$. This is in Berthelot, Breen, Messing, Théorie de Dieudonné cristalline, th. 3.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reminded of two papers by Maja Volkov, an erstwhile student of Jean-Marc Fontaine.  They are

MR2148801 (2006a:14027) 
Volkov, Maja 
A class of $p$-adic Galois representations arising from abelian varieties over $\Bbb Q_p$.
Math. Ann.  331  (2005),  no. 4, 889–923.

MR1837096 (2002d:11067) 
Volkov, Maja 
Les représentations $l$-adiques associées aux courbes elliptiques sur ${\Bbb Q}_p$. 
J. Reine Angew. Math. 535 (2001), 65–101.